# Error: Couldn't find constructor 'TypeMatcher'. .ancestorStateOfType(const TypeMatcher<AnimatedCircularChartState>());

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, pubspec

i even done that but errors are still there. i tried to downgrade the flutter version sdk to that project but didn't find the specific version and the ones i found are not helping.

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_circular_chart-0.1.0/lib/src/animated_circular_chart.dart:122:36: Error: Couldn't find constructor 'TypeMatcher'.
.ancestorStateOfType(const TypeMatcher\<AnimatedCircularChartState\>());
^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_circular_chart-0.1.0/lib/src/animated_circular_chart.dart:122:10: Error: The method 'ancestorStateOfType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.

- 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ancestorStateOfType'.
  .ancestorStateOfType(const TypeMatcher\<AnimatedCircularChartState\>());
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_circular_chart-0.1.0/lib/src/animated_circular_chart.dart:221:60: Error: The getter 'body2' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
- 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'body2'.
  widget.labelStyle ?? Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2;
  ^^^^^
  Failed to compile application.

So i downloaded this flutter project from github that was 3 years old so it was deprecated version, i fix the deprecated version error by following the documentation. now that error is fixed but after that i'm getting these errors above. i have tried so many things like pub upgrade, pub outdated and most of the commands like this but the error are still there. I somewhere read to add override dependencies: "dependency_overrides:
charts_flutter:
git:
url: https://github.com/google/charts
path: charts_flutter"
```

Comment: out of date package issue . you need to use updated package to sync with flutter latest versions

Comment: how can i get the updated packages?

Comment: use this package https://pub.dev/packages/circular_chart_flutter

Answer (score 0):

Since flutter_circular_chart package does not support null safety, you can use another package https://pub.dev/packages/circular_chart_flutter that provides null safety support. You can use this package in Flutter without downgrading the Flutter SDK version.